# Return values from multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an app where I want two start one of two activities based on the button I click on, then return certain values from the activity which was called. I know I should use requestCode to check the Activity. But either way, the app is assuming that the first activity is called. Here's part of my code in the main class.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.start:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, one.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, FIRST_CODE);
        break;      
    case R.id.qwe:
        Intent j = new Intent(this, two.class);
        startActivityForResult(j, SECOND_CODE);
        break;
    }
```

And later on,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode==FIRST_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            min = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("minutes"));
            sec = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("seconds"));
            test1.setText(min + ":" + sec);
        }
    }
    else if(requestCode==SECOND_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            runMin = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("minutes"));
            runSec = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("seconds"));
            test2.setText(runMin + ":" + sec);
        }
    }
}
```

In my classes 'one' and 'two', this is my code:

```
        min = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smin);
        sec = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ssec);            
        String mtime, stime;        
        mtime = min.getText().toString();
        stime = sec.getText().toString();
        dat2 = new Intent();
        dat2.putExtra("minutes", mtime);
        dat2.putExtra("seconds", stime);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, dat2);
        finish();
```

It's the same in both classes. Is that wrong? Thanks. :)

Comment: why you need to create two same kind of activity? else nothing is wrong.

Comment: I want to get two different times from both the activity. They're both basically the same but I want to store the different results in different variables so I can use them both later.

Comment: I think you should create only one activity, and in that activity differentiate time by some condition like boolean variable. And according to that variable state, you can store the result in other needed variables.

Answer (score 0):

app is not assuming first activity is called. check value of `requestCode` in `onActivityResult()` by Logging it,
use `Log.d("TAG",requestCode);` in the first line of onActivityResult();
 it will give you the the info abt which activity was called(with what request code)...

How the data is put in intent in both diff activities , and how it is processed back in this activity is entirely different thing...